# SSIS, Change Tracking, and Snapshot Isolation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I'm currently using SQL Server 2008 R2 Change Tracking (not Change Data Capture) and SSIS to extract incremental changes from several source databases.

Until now, I'd been using restored backups to do this so I didn't need to worry about Snapshot Isolation. However, I now need to point these packages at the production databases.

I know that setting the Snapshot Isolation Level on for the tracked databases is recommended to ensure consistency of the ETL extracts. I'm reluctant to do this because of possible degradation in performance.

Since I'm extracting late at night, is there some reason I can't use the following process?

1. Create a database snapshot for temporary use.
2. Get the Change Tracking Current Version of the Production Database.
3. Compare it with the previous successful run version.
4. Extract from the Database Snapshot instead of the Production Database.
5. After successful load, drop the Database Snapshot.

We're using 2008 R2 Enterprise Edition. is there any downside to this? Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, you can use a database snapshot for pulling the data. If anything it's more consistent that way because you get a snapshot of the entire database instead of a bunch of individual snapshots for each table. However, I'm eager to know what performance degradation your concerned with snapshot isolation causing.